# Magento2 Wrong Search Results

Tags: magento2, search, magento-search

im having some issues using Magento2 search engine.
Im using Magento 2.3.4 and have setup only the name (weight 10), meta-title (weight 5) and sku (Weight 1) as searchable.
Im having for example products with the names:

- Johana
- Joahna Absent
- Johana Regular

When i search for "Johana Absent", all the Johana products appear before the Johana Absent.

Can someone plese help me understand and solve this.

Regards

Comment: what catalog search engine are you using, MySql or ElasticSearch ?

Comment: Im using MySQL for the catalog search engine

Comment: Are you using a search extension? It looks like you are using an or type search not an and type search.

Comment: im not using any search extension.